# How to display ALSA raw MIDI connections and devices?

Tags: alsa, midi

For ALSA's MIDI sequencer connections, one can use `aconnect -lio`. If I run FluidSynth (or QSynth) with the `alsa_seq` MIDI driver, I can see FluidSynth displayed by `aconnect -lio`, but not anymore if I run FluidSynth with the `alsa_raw` driver, as I tried with an `hw:VirMIDI` device.

How can I display ALSA raw MIDI connections and devices like one can do for ALSA MIDI sequencers connections and clients?

Answer (score 5):

I can now answer half of my question, and may be the second half will never receive a positive answer.

One can list raw MIDI devices using `amidi -l`.

I don't see a way to list connections and it also only lists devices, not clients. Maybe there is nothing comparable to the ALSA's sequencer subscription mechanism with ALSA's raw MIDI, hence this part of the question will never receive the expected answer.

Please, people, still feel free to add your own answer, as I'm not fully happy with my own.

Comment: There are indeed no clients or subscriptions. You could inspect the device files with `fuser` or `lsof`.